# Do Not Hide Element When Hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hoverintent

I have an element that needs to slideDown when another element is hovered over, and remain visible when it is hovered over itself. Due to issues involving a design with a lot of overlapping elements and heavy use of z-index, I cannot nest the sliding element inside the hovered over element; they cannot even be siblings.

The HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
            <nav class="navvy">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#" class="one">One</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="two">Two</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav><!--nav-1-->
        </div><!--c-->
    </div><!--b-->
</div><!--a-->
<div class="slidedown slidedown-one">
    <div class="slide-content">
        One - text.
    </div><!--slide-content-->
</div><!--slidedown-->
<div class="slidedown slidedown-two">
    <div class="slide-content">
        Two - text.
    </div><!--slide-content-->
</div><!--slidedown-->
```

The jQuery (note: I'm using the hoverIntent plugin):

```
//Hide all slidedown divs
$('.slidedown').hide();

//Find the active class
var activeCl = $('.navvy').children('ul').find('.active').children('a').attr('class').split(' ')[0];

//Slide it down
var downSlide = function() {
    activeCl = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $('.slidedown-'+activeCl).slideDown(1000);
};

//Slide it up
var upSlide = function() {
    activeCl = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $('.slidedown-'+activeCl).delay(1000).slideUp(1000);
};

//Slide on hover
var slideHover = function() {
    $('.navvy').children('ul').find('li').children('a').hoverIntent({
        over: downSlide,
        out: upSlide
    });
};
slideHover();
```

It slides up and down fine, but I need it to not slide back up again when the mouse is inside of the div that slid down.

EDIT: Here is a JSFiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/qeLVU/2/

Comment: You can do it with a small timeout and some ingenuity, but the code seems rather messy and with the hoverIntent plugin (which I have no idea why you would need) you'll probably have to figure this out yourself, or at least set up a fiddle we can play with.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle example which shows the same behavior? I don't know the jQuery version you're using, too.

Comment: The code isn't exactly the same code I'm using--it's part of a large, complicated site and I simplified it here. There are several more lis with links that have their own associated slidedowns, and I don't want them sliding down all over the place if someone's moving their mouse all over them.

Comment: It's really not that hard to do, at least the priniciple isn't that hard, here's an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/dtrS8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you're over thinking this a bit. Just slide down or up when you hover on or off the `nav` link, and the same with the `div` itself.

```
$('.nav-1 ul li a').hover(function () {
    $('.slidedown-' + this.className).stop().slideDown();
}, function (){
    $('.slidedown-' + this.className).stop().slideUp();
});

$('.slidedown').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().slideDown();
}, function (){
    $(this).stop().slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cJWn8/

Comment: The problem with this is that the slidedown divs keep appearing when you mouse quickly over the list items. Would it be possible to incorporate hoverIntent with this so that doesn't happen?

Comment: I've never used hoverIntent, but it's almost certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

**using hoverIntent**

On your `hoverIntent`, it doesn't know it should also work on the content, you need to let it know what you want. `$('.navvy').children('ul').find('li').children('a').hoverIntent` would need to be more like `$('.navvy li').hoverIntent` with the slide content inside of the `li` so that they're both triggering the hover events.

so the html would be more like:

```
<nav class="navvy">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <div>One - text.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <div>Two - text.</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then the jquery becomes much easier, and you can do something like:

```
$('.navvy li').hoverIntent({//on common parent
    over: function() {
        $(this).addClass('active')//add active
        .children('div').stop(true,true).slideDown('slow');//slide down
    },
    out: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active')//remove active
        .children('div').stop(true).slideUp('fast');//slide up
    }
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/TCY78/

**jquery without intent or changing html**

If you are unable to change the `html` in this instance, or don't wish to rearrange it, then something like this will work on the existing `html`.

```
$('.navvy a').each(function(i) {//i gives you the index of the element
    var cl = $(this),//current link
        cc = $('.slidedown').eq(i),//current content
        dl = 0,//initial delay
        spd = 500,//speed
        tim = 250;//timeout
    cl.add(cc).hover(function() {//hover on
        !$('.slidedown:visible').length?dl=0:dl=spd;//set delay
        clearTimeout(cl.data('timer'));//clear timer
        cl.parent('li').addClass('active');//active on 
        cc.stop(true,true).delay(dl).slideDown(spd);//slide down
    }, function() {//hover off
        cl.parent('li').removeClass('active');//active off
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {//timeout
            cc.stop(true).slideUp(spd);//slide up
        }, tim);//delay
        cl.data('timer', timer);//set timer
    });
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/xn85z/

Comment: The suggested code works, but I am unable to incorporate hoverIntent: http://jsfiddle.net/xn85z/149/ --

On the proposed edits to my original code, hovering over the content doesn't keep the content from hiding: http://jsfiddle.net/qeLVU/3/

Comment: In your fiddle When I move my cursor quickly across the links, both content divs slide down rapidly on top of each other. I need hoverIntent to keep that from occuring.

Comment: wait, i think that's the expected behavior, what did you want to happen when you go back and forth really fast?

Comment: When I go back and forth really fast, I want it to do nothing, as in my initial fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qeLVU/2/

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a `hoverIntent` and `Jquery` solution, both with examples. The `hoverIntent` solution has rearranged markup to make things more simple.